# Saving a GAN in keras using tf.train.Checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

UPDATE: To solve this, I kept the checkpoint structure the same but wrote a custom train_step function, with the help of the repo linked in the accepted answer of the question linked below, which calculated the gradients and used apply_weights rather than compiling the model and using train_on_batch. This lets the full GAN state be restored. Sadly, with this method I'm fairly sure the dropout layers no longer work as the discriminator is able to work perfectly very early in the training which prevents the model from training properly. Nevertheless, the original problem is solved.

Original:

I am currently training a GAN in keras and trying to make it so that I can save the model and resume training later. Ordinarily in keras you'd simply use model.save(), however for a GAN if the discriminator and GAN (combined generator and discriminator, with discriminator weights not trainable) models are saved and loaded separately then the link between them is broken and the GAN will not function as expected. Someone asked a similar question here, [How to save and resume training a GAN with multiple model parts with Tensorflow 2/ Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69708977/how-to-save-and-resume-training-a-gan-with-multiple-model-parts-with-tensorflow), and was told to use tf.train.Checkpoint instead to save the full model at once as a checkpoint.

I've tried implementing this as follows:

```
def train(epochs, batch_size):
    checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(g_optimizer=g_optimizer,
                                     d_optimizer=d_optimizer,
                                     generator=generator,
                                     discriminator=discriminator,
                                     gan=gan
                                     )
    ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, 'checkpoints', max_to_keep=3)

    if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
        checkpoint.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
        discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optimizer)

        i = Input(shape=(None, latent_dims))
        lcs = generator(i)

        discriminator.trainable = False

        valid = discriminator(lcs)

        gan = Model(i, valid)
        gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optimizer)

    for epoch in epochs:
        #train discriminator...
        #train generator...
        ckpt_manager.save()
```

where g_optimizer, d_optimizer are just `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` objects and generator, discriminator and gan are `tf.keras.Model` objects.

When I use this approach, the link between the gan model and the discriminator is preserved after loading in the checkpoint. The training works normally at first, but after I stop and then resume training using the checkpoint the discriminator loss starts massively increasing and the generated data becomes nonsensical.

Recompiling the models are loading the checkpoint like this was only way I could think of doing it which uses the last state of the optimizer, but clearly something isn't right - rather than resuming the training from where it was, this approach is massively disrupting the training.

Have I used tf.train.Checkpoint incorrectly for what I'm trying to do? Please let me know if there's any more information you need to be able to address the question.

Edit, have added full code by request:

Here is the code that creates the models in the first place and then trains them, in this setup the models are compiled initially when first created, and then compiled again if resuming from a checkpoint using the latest optimizer state. I appreciate it's weird to compile twice but I couldn't think of another way to use the latest optimizer state from the checkpoint, if there's a better way I'm very happy to change it. Note, the unusual GRU-based GAN is because I'm testing out being able to generate variable length time-series. There's a lot of data specific stuff in there but hopefully on the whole it makes sense. `train_df` is just a pandas DataFrame containing all the training data

```
def build_generator():
    input = Input(shape=(None, latent_dims))
    gru1 = GRU(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(input)
    gru2 = GRU(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True (gru1)
    output = GRU(9, return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid')(gru2)
    model = Model(input, output)
    return model

def build_discriminator():
    input = Input(shape=(None, 9))
    gru1 = GRU(100, return_sequences=True)(input)
    gru2 = GRU(100, return_sequences=True)(gru1)
    output = GRU(1, activation='sigmoid')(gru2)
    model = Model(input, output)
    return model

d_optimizer = opt.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
g_optimizer = opt.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

# Build discriminator
discriminator = build_discriminator()
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optimizer)

# Build generator
generator = build_generator()

# Build combined model
i = Input(shape=(None, latent_dims))
lcs = generator(i)
discriminator.trainable = False
valid = discriminator(lcs)

gan = Model(i, valid)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optimizer)

def train(epochs, batch_size=1): #Only works with batch size of 1 currently
    sne = train_df.sn.unique()
    n_batches = int(len(sne) / batch_size)
    rng = np.random.default_rng(123)

    checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(g_optimizer=g_optimizer,
                                     d_optimizer=d_optimizer,
                                     generator=generator,
                                     discriminator=discriminator,
                                     gan=gan
                                     )
    ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, 'checkpoints', max_to_keep=3)
    if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
        checkpoint.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
        discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optimizer)

        i = Input(shape=(None, latent_dims))
        lcs = generator(i)

        discriminator.trainable = False
        valid = discriminator(lcs)

        gan = Model(i, valid)
        gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optimizer)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        rng.shuffle(sne)
        g_losses, d_losses = [], []
        for batch in range(n_batches):
            real = np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1, (batch_size, 1)) # Used instead of np.zeros to avoid zero gradients
            fake = np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.0, (batch_size, 1)) # Used instead of np.ones to avoid zero gradients

        # Select real data
        sn = sne[batch]
        sndf = train_df[train_df.sn == sn]
        X = sndf[['g_t', 'r_t', 'i_t', 'z_t', 'g', 'r', 'i', 'z', 'g_err', 'r_err', 'i_err', 'z_err']].values

        X = X.reshape((1, *X.shape))

        noise = rand.normal(size=(batch_size, latent_dims))
        noise = np.reshape(noise, (batch_size, 1, latent_dims))
        noise = np.repeat(noise, X.shape[1], 1)

        gen_lcs = generator.predict(noise)

        # Train discriminator
        d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, real)
        d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_lcs, fake)
        d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
        
        # Train generator
        noise = rand.normal(size=(2 * batch_size, latent_dims))
        noise = np.reshape(noise, (2 * batch_size, 1, latent_dims))
        noise = np.repeat(noise, X.shape[1], 1)

        gen_labels = np.zeros((2 * batch_size, 1))
        g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, gen_labels)
        g_losses.append(g_loss)
        d_losses.append(d_loss)
    ckpt_manager.save()
    full_g_loss = np.mean(g_losses)
    full_d_loss = np.mean(d_losses)
    print(f'{epoch + 1}/{epochs} g_loss={full_g_loss}, d_loss={full_d_loss})

train()
```

Comment: Why are you compiling your models again? Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, I'm compiling again to try and make sure that the latest optimizer state is being used

Comment: can you show your whole training loop

Comment: I'd added the full training loop, there's a bunch of specific stuff to the data in there but hopefully it all makes sense

Comment: where are you using the `gan` model?

Comment: sorry, was a typo, have fixed now, the model was called "combined" in an earlier version of the code which I copied, now called "gan"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following checkpoint structure, your model should work properly:

```py
checkpoint_dir = 'checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_opt=generator_opt,
                                  discriminator_opt=discriminator_opt,
                                  gan_opt=gan_opt,
                                  generator=generator,
                                  discriminator=discriminator,
                                  GAN = GAN
                                  )

ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, checkpoint_dir, max_to_keep=3)
if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
  checkpoint.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
  print ('Latest checkpoint restored!!')
```

Note that the `GAN` model has its own optimizer. And then in your training loop, just save checkpoints at certain intervals, for example every 10 epochs.

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
...
...
...
  if epoch%10 == 0:
    ckpt_manager.save()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this! I'm fairly sure I have this checkpoint structure now, I don't have a generator optimizer as it is never compiled, in my code g_optimizer is for the GAN. Do you know if the way I'm compiling the model again after checkpoint.restore is correct? The training still doesn't seem to continue from where it was after restoring the model

Comment: I do not think it is necessary.